# Update a value inside array in an object using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hi I want to change a status as 'N' for the images which I have selected

Following is my json:

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5b9f95c2e7d46ca2bffb8a38"),
        "inspection_id" : "00000000dc174c30682f9bdd",
        "__v" : 0,
        "client_id" : "00000000d080d32e387121bf",
        "created_date" : ISODate("2018-09-17T12:44:01.843Z"),
        "images" : [ 
            {
                "img_name" : "1537185218432-dnIyQ1tL4di9jBmP.png",
                "type" : "png",
                "file_size" : "6985",
                "path" : "/uploads/inspection/00000000d080d32e387121bf/images/1537185218432-dnIyQ1tL4di9jBmP.png",
                "status" : "Y",
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b9f95c23c4a081a34b4cf1a")
            }, 
            {
                "img_name" : "1537185451994-FS2yNFcNKhASSHqe.jpg",
                "type" : "jpg",
                "file_size" : "41341",
                "path" : "/uploads/inspection/00000000d080d32e387121bf/images/1537185451994-FS2yNFcNKhASSHqe.jpg",
                "status" : "Y",
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b9f96ac5700fc07000ee07f")
            }, 
            {
                "img_name" : "1537186207337-hhz5XrpmH48YW47A.jpg",
                "type" : "jpg",
                "file_size" : "41341",
                "path" : "/uploads/inspection/00000000d080d32e387121bf/images/1537186207337-hhz5XrpmH48YW47A.jpg",
                "status" : "N",
                "_id" : ObjectId("5b9f999f5700fc07000ee081")
            }]
    }
```

I tried this following query:

```
mongo.inspectionmedia.update({'images._id' : {$in:media_id} }, { $set : { 'images.$.status' : 'N'} },{multi: true},function(err,output){
            if(err){
                console.log(err)
                res.json("err");
            }
            else{
                res.json("ok");  
            }
        });
```

In media_id am having array of id for those id only status have to change.

My issue is value is updating but for the first value in array not for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you'd want to use [arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/):

```
db.inspectionmedia.update({}, {
    $set : { 'images.$[i].status' : 'N'} 
}, {
    multi: true,
    arrayFilters: [
        {'i._id': { $in:media_id}}
    ]
}, function(err,output){
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
        res.json("err");
    }
    else{
        res.json("ok");  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB has introduced the filtered positional operator $[] which can be used to update multiple elements of an array which match an array filter condition. You can read more about this operator here:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

```
      db.inspectionmedia.update(
        {$set: { 'images.$[element].status' : 'N'} },
        {multi:true,
         arrayFilters: [
           {'element._id': { $in:media_id}}
         ]
        },
        function(err,updated){
           console.log(updated);
       });
```